# What if I need to render data from fetch?

Tags: reactjs

I need data in my render method that are taken from API. I get the error:
"Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method".

Is there a way to wait till response is ready and then call render method?

Comment: You are using `this.setState` in a component that has ben unmounted. You could have an instance variable `_isMounted` that you set to `false` in `componentDidUnmount` that you check if it is `true` before putting something in your state in the request callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The componentDidMount() lifecycle method is the best place to fetch data. In the render method, you can check if data is already set and then display the result or a spinner if it is null.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.mydomain.com')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ data }));
  }

  ...
}

export default App;
```

You can find a more detailed description here https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data/